# Glimpse issue on starting Activity on Kitkat

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have two activity say "A" and "B". "A" activity is a lockActivity which comes to front when app brought from background and "B" is a launcher activity of app.

I am showing "A" in onResume() method of "B" if app came from the background.
Observed that "B" is glimpsed for a second then "A" comes to front.

I have also tried to place showing activity code in onRestart() and onStart(), but didn't work.

please somebody suggest me a solution.

Note:- Issue is produce only in Nexus 4(Kitkat) and Nexus 5.